# Why does typescript generics infer different types if array member is wrapped?

Tags: javascript, typescript

*This may be a duplicate question; however I can't seem to find an answer, so please feel free to point me somewhere if it has already been answereded.*

When working with generics, I find that typescript infers different types depending on whether I wrap a generic used as an array member. For example,

```js
// Set up
type Wrapped<I> = { _i: I };

// Not working example
function foo1<TInner extends unknown>(bar: Wrapped<TInner>[]) {
  return bar;
}
const a = foo1([{ _i: 5 }, { _i: "six" }]); // TInner = number, compiler complains about second array member despite the fact that it's inferring it

// Working example
function foo2<TInner extends Wrapped<unknown>>(bar: TInner[]) {
  return bar;
}
const b = foo2([{ _i: 5 }, { _i: "six" }]); // TInner = Wrapped<number> | Wrapped<string>
```

Why is this the case? Is there something in the documentation I'm missing? More generically, can anyone point me to a good explanation of how typescript does inference of generics?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way that the code is written very closely.

```
// Slightly edited given example

type Wrapped<I> = { _i: I };

function foo<T extends unknown>(baz: Wrapped<T>[]) {}

foo1([ { _i: 5 }, { _i: "six" } ]);

function bar<T extends Wrapped<unknown>>(baz: T[]) {}

foo2([ { _i: 5 }, { _i: "six" } ]);
```

The way `foo`'s generic parameter is defined, `T extends unknown`, means that `T` can be anything, denoted by the `unknown`, but it's **1** thing.

The actual function's parameter is `Wrapped<T>[]`; breaking it down, `foo` accepts an array of `Wrapped<T>`, meaning it accepts a list of `Wrapped` objects, but every one of them must have the **same type**, so it could accept `[ { _i: 1 }, { _i: 2 }, { _i: 3 } ]`, or `[ { _i: 'a' }, { _i: 'b' }, { _i: 'c' } ]`, but it cannot create a union/tuple as it's output, so something like `[ { _i: 'a' }, { _i: 2 }, { _i: Symbol(NaN) } ]` would fail, because this type is actually `Wrapped<string | number | symbol>[]`, whereas the former two were `Wrapped<number>[]`, and `Wrapped<string>[]`, respectively.

`bar`, on the other hand, is defined as `<T extends Wrapped<unknown>>`. In this case, `T` is just an object of the type `Wrapped`, without care to what it's type parameter is, as long as it has the general shape of a `Wrapped` object.
Here, it can take an array of `Wrapped` objects, regardless of whether they are all of the same types, or not.

Summing it up, `foo` is accepting a contiguous array of the same type, whereas `bar` is accepting an array of any `Wrapped` objects.

Comment: Honestly, now that I look at it, this is a poor explanation, since to me, it just "makes sense," without thought.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why specifically since number | string extends unknown, does that make sense?